# Drupal node_load display all fields

Tags: views, nodes, theming, entities

I have a template for a view in which I load a node. Is there a way to get the value of all fields from that node? Like, if I add another field in CCK it will appear automatically in the template.

Something like:

```
foreach $node->field
     print $value
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`node_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_view/7)

```
<?php
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $node_view = node_view($node);
  $rendered_node = drupal_render($node_view);
  echo $rendered_node;
?>
```

Read: [Rendering Drupal 7 fields (the right way)](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way)

Comment: Thank you very much!! Also, is there a way to theme the printed fields? Do in need to use hook_node_view for that?

Comment: Nevermind, I've solved the field theming by overriding field--ctname.tpl.php